# Where does `Deno.env` got its data from?

Tags: deno

I've seen that `Deno.env` seems to get an information about my PC and some path.

But where does it knows it from? How do I able to fill my own `.env` file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The information contained in `Deno.env` is the same that was provided in Node.js.

These variables are called environment variables.

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html

This is classical for a CLI (like `deno`) to access user environment variables.

Now if you are trying to fill your environment variables, from an .env file, you need something like this:

https://deno.land/x/dotenv

You can display more information about your `Deno.env` by running this:

```sh
$ deno eval "console.log(Deno.env.toObject())"
```

OR

```js
// file.ts
console.log(Deno.env.toObject())
```

https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.env

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to fill your own `.env` you should use the `dotenv/mod.ts` package:

```js
import { config } from "https://deno.land/x/dotenv/mod.ts";

const greeting = config().GREETING

console.log(greeting);
```

The `.env` file:

```
GREETING = Hello!
```

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/pietvanzoen/deno-dotenv/blob/master/README.md) for all the options.

Comment: Negative feedback is always welcome, whoever gave -1

Comment: This is now a part of `std`, you can find it [here](https://github.com/denoland/deno_std/tree/main/dotenv)

Answer (score 2):

If we want to store our credentials or other data in .env file then it should be created at the root of your project folder(/my_deno_api/.env), then use package dotenv/load.ts

import "https://deno.land/x/dotenv/load.ts";

const jwt_key = Deno.env.get("JWT_KEY");

For more info check this [documentation](https://github.com/pietvanzoen/deno-dotenv/blob/master/README.md)

Thanks,